CiviSMS is not selecting the Primary mobile number
Using the Actions menu to send an outbound SMS. Where contacts have more than one valid mobile number, the activity is not loaded with the number that is set to Primary. It loads a number that is not Primary instead. So obvs if there are several non-primary numbers it's all a bit random and you have to manually search for the Primary number. I'm using the Clickatell extension.
CiviCRM 5.72.1

i don't recall the specifics, and don't recall it relating to it not using the Primary phone if that was a mobile number, but iirc we had to add a customisation to a client that added a 'use for SMS' field for any mobile phone record. it also mean folk could nominate more than one phone to receive the SMS - which was important for them.
